# How do I open up a text file and use it in this code to sort ip adresses python

Tags: python, python-2.7

So instead of setting the ips to sort through I have a plethora of them in a text file that I need to sort though how do I open it up and see which ones occurred most?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import iplib

ips = []

for ip in ["192.168.100.56", "192.168.0.3", "192.0.0.192", "8.0.0.255"]:
       ips.append(iplib.IPv4Address(ip))

def ip_compare(x, y):
       return cmp(x.get_dec(), y.get_dec())

ips.sort(ip_compare)

print [ip.address for ip in ips]
```

and the text file looks like this

```
113.177.60.181 - - [05/Jul/2013:03:27:07 -0500] "GET /email/13948staticvoid.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 17181 "http://www.bereans.org/email/index.php" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0)"
113.177.60.181 - - [05/Jul/2013:03:27:07 -0500] "GET /email/13948staticvoid.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 17181 "http://www.bereans.org/email/index.php" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0)"
```

Comment: Your question is quite cryptic. If I understand correctly, you have a file full of IP addresses and you want to determine which of them occurred most often in the file. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct, I figured i could use the same code I have if I knew how to open the text file up in it or pass it to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter
with open('path/to/file') as infile:
    counts = Counter(line.split('-', 1)[0].strip() for line in infile)
IPs = counts.most_common() # thanks @Jon Clements
# equivalent to IPs = sorted(counts, key=counts.__getitem__, reverse=True)
```

There you go! `IPs` now has a list of the IP addresses in your text file, sorted in order from most frequent to least frequent

Comment: Could use `counts.most_common()` with no argument to do that sort... (which may be slightly less cryptic to some) and also means if the top 10 (or whatever) are required - it's straight forward to do... (it'll also give you IP and count pairs as opposed to just the IP)

Comment: the text file looks like this

Comment: @ChingOwn: like what?

Comment: Like i just edited above in the first post If their is a better way to set it up please let me know